# Variable Timeperiod with a dash

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to create a variables called Reporting_Period, which I retrieve from the date variable: Return Closing Date.
Reporting_Period needs to look like 2019 - 2020 or 2020 - 2021 etc

I am having problems incorporating that dash and I tried +' - '+
The error message I am getting is:

> Operand type clash: date is incompatible with int

What do I need to do?

The code I am trying is as below:

```
 ,((YEAR ([Return Closing Date])) +' - '+ (DATEADD(YEAR, -1,([Return Closing Date])))) AS [Reporting_Period]
```

Comment: `CONVERT` or `CAST` your `INT`s to `VARCHAR`s before trying to concatenate them.

Comment: Use concat() ... no nead to cast or convert  concat( Year1 ,' - ', Year2 )

Comment: You could also use datename() which returns a string  ...  datename(year,SomeDate1)+' - '+datename(year,SomeDate2)

Comment: Excellent @JohnCappelletti, is worked:                                                     ,CONCAT(YEAR ([Return Closing Date]), '-' ,(YEAR(DATEADD(YEAR, -1,([Return Closing Date]))))) AS [Reporting_Period]

Comment: Others have provided the answer, but here's the explanation: You've run afoul of [data type precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) which determines how SQL Server handles expressions that combine data types. When you mix strings and `int` values the rule is to convert the strings to `int` and then perform the operation, in this case adding (`+`) numbers rather than concatenating strings. `' - '` makes a lousy `int`.

Answer (score 0):

Excellent @JohnCappelletti, is worked:

```
,CONCAT(YEAR ([Return Closing Date]), '-' ,(YEAR(DATEADD(YEAR, -1,([Return Closing Date]))))) AS [Reporting_Period]
```